# What's an "M shape in the seat"?

Tags: the-pretenders-and-the-pulsar

Page 248 chapter 2

> *Everything inside was white, with comfortably upholstered sixties design seats that had an M shape in the seat with just a headrest.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Pretenders & The Pulsar](https://www.amazon.it/Pretenders-Pulsar-English-Florence-Kembaren-ebook/dp/B0854LHFNT), Florence Kembaren Book (Kindle edition)</sup></sub>

What’s an "*M shape in the seat*"?
Whith just a headrest? It’s not clear to me.The chair had only a headrest?no backseat?

Answer (score 7):

I'm pretty sure they're referring to bucket seats with a headrest integrated directly into the seat (which was the style at the time).

[image]

Comment: More likely it refers to the squab, not the back.

Comment: @andy256 - That's a possibility. I'm not sure it's more or less likely either way.

Comment: Well I was expecting something totally different.

Comment: @Valorum Sorry, out of SE practice, I should have explained more. But as I re-read the OP, the connection "with just a headrest" does seem to tie the visual imagery to the back of the seat. +1

Comment: With just a headrest? It looks she’s telliing the chair have only a headrest  with no backseat